# Como faço para esconder o nome do Controller na url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Gostaria de saber como faço para esconder o nome do controlador no Codeigniter.

Sabendo que o codeigniter funciona da seguinte maneira:

```
www.meusite.com/CONTROLADOR/FUNÇÃO
```

Ex: `www.meusite.com/dashboard/login`  quero que fique `www.meusite.com/login`

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Talvez com .htaccess..

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar as [rotas](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)
No arquivo **application/config/routes.php**

Tem um array chamado '$route' onde consegue definir suas rotas

```
$route['product/:num'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';
```

No seu caso acho que ficaria

```
$route['login'] = 'dashboard/login';
```

Comment: Poderia me dizer como ficaria a linha de código do meu exemplo?

Comment: editei a resposta